# Unable to retrieve hibernate foreign keys from a servlet context

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

I can't read the ids of referenced entities using Hibernate, Tomcat and MySQL.

Example, running the following code:

```
List<UserAccount> users = listEntities(UserAccount.class);
    for (UserAccount user : users) {
        UserAccountStatusCatalog status = user.getStatus();
        System.out.println("[User (" + user.getId() + ") : "+user.getAccountName()+"] - " + status + ": " + status.getId());
    }
```

Will give the following output in a simple Java application or servlet context using SQL server DB

> [User (1) : system] - Suspended: 15020
>   [User (2) : admin] - Active: 15010
>   [User (4) : test] - Active: 15010

And this from within a servlet context using MySQL DB

> [User (1) : system] - Suspended: 0
>   [User (2) : admin] - Active: 0
>   [User (4) : test] - Active: 0

This is on a Tomcat 7 server running Java 8
Database is MySQL 5.5 and I'm using hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final

I have tested a lot of different approaches such as changing Hibernate version, changing DB to MariaDB (not working) and to a SQL server (works perfectly).
I've tested on Tomcat 6,7 and 8 (same result, not working)
Tested on java 7 and 8 (same result, not working)

**Entities**

```
@Entity(name = "UserAccount")
@Table(name = "user_account")
@Audited
public class UserAccount {  
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_status", nullable=false, foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = ForeignKeys.FK_USERACCOUNT_STATUS))
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    private UserAccountStatusCatalog status;
    [...]


@Entity
@Table(name="user_account_status_catalog")
public class UserAccountStatusCatalog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = ID_COLUMN_NAME, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

**So my question is**
Does anyone have any experience with this particular issue or have any pointers about where I can continue debugging since I'm all out of ideas about what to do.

Comment: Can you share code of `UserAccount` and `UserAccountStatusCatalog` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this on my own. It turns out that the culprit was javassist-3.16.0 import.
After replacing this old version with the javassist3.20.0 import everything worked the way it was supposed to.

So for anyone experiencing similar problems, replacing this import is a good place to start.